# format text from file in javalin/java get

Tags: java, javalin

I made a get in my javalin that sends back data from a text file.

this is the get method:

```
app.get("/info", ctx -> {

            // stream, streamReader en buffer om file uit te lezen
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("wedstrijd.txt");
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

            // geef alle regels van de file terug
            ctx.result(reader.lines().collect(Collectors.joining()));
        });
```

But this gives back the data in one big line of text.

How can I format this text to make it look a bit better?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "better"? You can edit the question to show a sample of what you have, and a sample of what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try adding a line break at the in your `ctx.result(reader.lines().collect(Collectors.joining()));` line, like this

```
ctx.result(reader.lines().collect(Collectors.joining()) + "\n");
```

You can also refer to this question:
[Add new line to bottom of StringJoiner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43927608/add-new-line-to-bottom-of-stringjoiner)